# Database table names case sensitivity

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i got this script and trying to install it, but i am having problem: Here is the image:

http://prntscr.com/9hcj3d

Here is database.php file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '*****',
    'username' => '******',
    'password' => '*******',
    'database' => '********',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
    'dbprefix' => 'WS_',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache/others',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '{PRE}',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

There is database created and i imported this file that came up with the theme:

http://www.speedyshare.com/VNSkW/base.sql

I can't figure out where is problem i am not that good at php, if you need any other files i will upload them and post here.

Here is web link: http://chwallpapers.cf/

PS: My english is bad, sry.

Comment: Are you sure that table `WS_wallpapers` is in your database?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9hctef I Guess this is it?

Comment: Try to use `wc_wallpapers`, maybe table names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yea works now, thanks bro i was trying to figure out this for a long time.

Comment: Edited a question to be more specific and searchable.

Answer (score 3):

As we found out - table names *can be* case sensitive.

And even mysql warns about it:

> This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Full text, for example, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

So your query should be rewritten to use `ws_wallpapers` instead of `WS_wallpapers`